# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Game Development's [fourth moderator election](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: Evorlor] [image: Almo]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5801219546152960).

Comment: Apologies for the delayed results - thanks for your patience.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congrats and welcome!

Comment: Congrats! See you around the Stack ;D

Comment: Congratulations Evorlor and Almo! Looking forward to working with you both!

Comment: Woohoo! Welcome to the team!